# Printing Elements of 3D Array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int ***my3DArray;
int length, width, height;

bool doAgain = true;
string answer("");
string yes("y");

do{
cout << "Enter length: ";
cin >> length;
cout << "\nEnter width: ";
cin >> width;
cout << "\nEnter height: ";
cin >> height;

srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

my3DArray = new int**[length];

for (int i= 0; i < length; ++i){

    my3DArray[i] = new int*[width];

    for(int j = 0; j< width; ++j){

    my3DArray[i][j] = new int[height];

    for(int k = 0; k < height; ++k){

        my3DArray[i][j][k] = rand()%100;

        cout << my3DArray[i][j][k] << " ";

       do{
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
                for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
                    for (int k=0; k< height; k++){
                        cout << "\n\nEnter coodinates: ";
                        cin >> i;
                        cin >> j;
                        cin >> k;
                        cout << "Element is " << my3DArray[i][j][k];
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << "Find another element? (Y/n)";

            cin >> answer;

            if(answer.compare(yes) == 0)
                doAgain = true;

            else doAgain = false;
        }

        while(doAgain == true);

            }
            cout << endl;

        }
        cout << endl;

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){

            delete[]my3DArray[i][j];

        }

            delete[]my3DArray[i];
    }

        delete[]my3DArray;

        my3DArray = NULL;

        cout << "Again? (y, n)";

        cin >> answer;

        if(answer.compare(yes) == 0)
            doAgain = true;

        else doAgain = false;

}

while(doAgain == true);

}
```

This prints a 3D array of integers, I need to write a function called tick that returns the element of user specified coordinates i j k. That part of the code is this

```
do{
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
                for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
                    for (int k=0; k< height; k++){
                        cout << "\n\nEnter coodinates: ";
                        cin >> i;
                        cin >> j;
                        cin >> k;
                        cout << "Element is " << my3DArray[i][j][k];
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << "Find another element? (Y/n)";

            cin >> answer;

            if(answer.compare(yes) == 0)
                doAgain = true;

            else doAgain = false;
        }

        while(doAgain == true);
```

when I have this in my code, it doesnt print out the 3D array and I get a segmentation fault when it's supposed to print the element. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

instead of `int ***my3DArray` use `int my3DArray[256][256]` when declaring an array is just a pointer to the first item in the list. you then run a for loop to go through that list.